# How to view the userID in the Google Analytics interface？

Tags: ios, google-analytics, userid, tracker

Below is the code for tracking the userId that I set in the iOS project, but I can't find the word userId in the Google Analytics interface. How can I view the userId(“my_user_id”) that I uploaded to the Google Analytics interface?

```
guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker else { return }

tracker.set(kGAIUserId, value: “my_user_id”)

guard let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(withCategory: “UX”,
                                                             action: “User Sign In”,
                                                             label: nil,
                                                             value: nil) else { return }

tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Comment: See: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123670. This would also be useful: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you first need to enable the UserId feature in GAI.

Comment: Yes, I followed the documentation, I opened the user ID function in the Tracking Info and created the view, but I did not view the user ID override option in the left menu of Google Analytics.Where am I doing something wrong? Where can I view the userId?

Answer (score 0):

You can view a [User-ID Coverage report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123670)

NOTE: This report is visible only in User-ID enabled properties, and only in views for that property that have not been User-ID enabled.

> The User-ID Coverage report is an overview of the distribution of assigned User IDs among all of your traffic. You can use this report to see the total number of sessions and compare the proportion in which users are assigned a User ID to the proportion in which users aren’t assigned a User ID.

Related [article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) which could be helpful

Another thing to note: [source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en)

> the userId field is not available as a dimension in reports and can not be exported from Analytics.